# Encountering a vague RuntimeWarning when trying to plot a linear regression model using sk learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, python-3.6

```
import pandas
import math
from csv import reader
import sys
import numpy as np
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt
import warnings
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn import linear_model  


def fxn():
    warnings.warn("Runtime Warning",RuntimeWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
def costcomp(X,y,theta):
    inner=np.power(((X*theta.T)-y),2)
    return np.sum(inner)/(2*len(X))


def gradient(theta,X,y,lr,itr):
    temp=np.matrix(np.zeros(theta.shape))
    parameters=int(theta.ravel().shape[1])
    cost=np.zeros(itr)
    for i in range(itr):
        err=(X*theta.T)-y
        for j in range(parameters):
            tem=np.multiply(err,X[:,j])
            temp[0,j]=theta[0,j]-((lr/len(X))*np.sum(tem))
        theta=temp
        cost[i]=costcomp(X,y,theta)

    return theta,cost


dataset = pandas.read_csv("PYTHONFINAL.csv",names=['Month','Year','Day','Time','SpeedLimit','Age','Accidents'])
dataset = (dataset- dataset.mean()) / dataset.std()  
dataset.insert(0, 'Ones', 1)

cols=dataset.shape[1]
X=dataset.iloc[:,0:cols-1]
y=dataset.iloc[:,cols-1:cols]
X = np.matrix(X.values)  
y = np.matrix(y.values)
theta = np.matrix(np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0]))
X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=7)
print(costcomp(X_train,y_train,theta))
learningrate=0.01
iterations=2000
grad,costf=gradient(theta,X_train,y_train,learningrate,iterations)
print(grad)
print(costcomp(X_train,y_train,grad))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))  
ax.plot(np.arange(iterations),costf, 'r')  
ax.set_xlabel('Iterations')  
ax.set_ylabel('Cost')  
ax.set_title('Error vs. Training Epoch')

#           **PROBLEM STARTS HERE**

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
x = np.array(X[:, 1].A1)  
f = model.predict(X).flatten()

plt.show()


x = np.linspace(dataset.Month.min(), dataset.Month.max(), 100)  
f = grad[0, 0] + (grad[0, 1] * x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))  
ax.plot(x, f, 'r', label='Prediction')  
ax.scatter(dataset.Month, dataset.Accidents, label='Traning Data')  
ax.legend(loc=2)  
ax.set_xlabel('Month')  
ax.set_ylabel('Accidents')  
ax.set_title('Predicted Accidents vs. Month')
```

ERROR:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 1226
    warnings.warn(mesg, RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: internal gelsd driver lwork query error, required iwork dimension not returned. This is likely the result of LAPACK bug 0038, fixed in LAPACK 3.2.2 (released July 21, 2010). Falling back to 'gelss' driver.
```

PROBLEM:

I have been wanting to plot a graph to see whether the linear regression model build is effective or not.Therefore,I want a regression line plot for the model i built and the original dataset used for this program.The head(20) values of dataset I have used is provided in the image attached.

[Dataset for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swkwu.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to suppress these special warnings.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", module="scipy", message="^internal gelsd")
```

Comment: Thank you, the warning is not showing anymore , can i get more help from you on how to plot the predated accidents vs actual accidents dataset in reference to this dataset. It'll be extremely helpful.